# Launching Kotlin coroutine inside suspend fun inheriting parental thead without waiting it to finish

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm quite new to Kotlin Coroutines and just trying to achieve some basic goals. Imagine having some sort of service that should run endless loop in the background. I want to put the endless loop implicitly on the thread that caller of the `initService` method runs in. In the real app the service is initialized in the separate thread context from the context in which writer to the channel exists. This is the reason to use channel here. Moreover, `initService()` happens in a long nested chain of `suspend` methods calls and should remain implicit for the sake of the design simplicity.

According to the official Kotlin guide to coroutines I used `coroutineScope` designed for structured parallelism and calling async operations with `launch` and `async` `CoroutineScope` extension methods. The tricky part is that even though `coroutineScope` without any parameters inherits the parent scope and thus the thread in which the coroutine is running, it overrides the `Job` of the parent scope and thus the `coroutineScope` method call never leaves until all the children `launch` and `async` jobs are finished.

I wrote the following code snippet to demonstrate the issue. The service is initialized and dialed with in the same coroutine only in test purposes. In the real code these are totally different parts of the app. Unfortunately, his code never leaves `initService` and runs forever.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.*

class Service {
    val channel = Channel<String>()

    var job: Job? = null
    
    suspend fun initService(): Unit = coroutineScope {
        job = launch { sendChannelData() }
    }

    suspend fun stopService() {
        job?.cancel()
    }

    suspend fun sendChannelData(): Unit = coroutineScope {
        for (message in channel) {
            launch { pretendDoingSomeBlockingIO(message) }
        }
    }

    suspend fun pretendDoingSomeBlockingIO(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }
}


fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val someService = Service();
    
    someService.initService()
    println("Started service")
    
    someService.channel.send("Msg")
    delay(100)
    
    someService.stopService()
    println("Stopped service")
}
```

However, if we move the body of `initService` out and perform launching the `sendChannelData` right in the `main`, everything works as desired. I have already explained the reason why the code above blocks but the described solution is *not* appropriate for me due to the reasons I've already mentioned above.

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val someService = Service();
    
    someService.job = launch { someService.sendChannelData() }
    println("Started service")
```

Kotlin guidelines also suggest the following method of creating background activities:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#coroutine-scope But that solution enforces to pass the context explicitly around the code which would lead to modify my code a lot.

Comment: `coroutineScope {}` is used for parallel decomposition, and hence waits for all the children before resumes. You should instead pass the CoroutineContext there add element to it, launch into that, and make the function non-suspend.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, yes, I've both the reason and the solution you mentioned described in my text and I've the explanation why I want to avoid this approach. But it seems to me after long hours of Googling to be inevitable.

Comment: Making your caller `launch` your function instead is the correct design decision.  Kotlin is deliberately trying to force you to make sure that when a coroutine function returns, it's entirely done.